# How to Access a array in the structure after assigning the structure variable to a pointer without arrow operator

Tags: c, pointers, structure, double-pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct dog
{
    int name[10];
    char breed[10];
    int age;
    char color[10];
};

int main()
{
struct dog frodo;
struct dog **ptr=&frodo.name;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
frodo.name[i]=i;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
printf(" frodo.name[%d]%d\n",i,frodo.name[i]);

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
printf(" ptr =%d\n",ptr[i]);
}
```

I tried using double pointer but the index is not matching when value is being printed.

O/P:
frodo.name[0]0
frodo.name[1]1

ptr =0
ptr =2

Comment: The compiler error should be pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: You are declaring ptr to be a pointer to a pointer to struct dog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question indicates that you are new to C and still learning fundamentals,
so in order to help you I'll go through your code and explain what it does, and
then provide that code fixed to do what I think you are trying to do.  I will
try to be precise and thorough at the risk of sounding pedantic.

Consider this declaration:

```
int name[10];
```

This defines `name` as a field in `struct dog` which declares name to be the
type of "an array of 10 `int`s".  Note that an array can be assigned to a
pointer to its "inner" type (`int`), in which assignment it is said to "decay"
into a "pointer to `int`".  So `int * pint = name;` is valid code which show
this facility in C.  None-the-less, the type of `name` is "array of 10 `int`s".
This if you take it's address (`&name`) you don't get a "pointer to `int`; you
get a "pointer to an array of 10 `int`s".

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct dog
{
    int name[10];
    char breed[10];
    int age;
    char color[10];
};
```

So you declare a new "aggregate type", `struct dog`, whose objects will contain
a field called `name` whose type is an "array of 10 `int`s", followed by a field
called `breed` whose type is an "array of 10 `char`s", followed by a field `age`
whose type is `int`, then a field `color` with type "array of 10 `char`s".

```
int main()
{
struct dog frodo;
```

Define an object `frodo` of type `struct dog`, which then contains all of the
fields of a struct dog.  It is allocated memory on the stack, which will be
cleaned up and removed when `main` returns.

```
struct dog **ptr=&frodo.name;
```

Here is the first sign of misunderstanding. If you were to declare a variable
`ptr_to_dog` like this: `struct dog * ptr_to_dog`, you would declare it as a
pointer ("address of") an object whose type is `struct dog`, or "pointer to
`struct dog`", for short. `frodo` is such an object, so setting pointer to this
address of `frodo` is valid: `ptr_to_dog = &frodo;`.  `&frodo` is an expression
which takes the address of the `frodo` object, so the type of this expression
"pointer to `struct dog`", which matches the type of `ptr_to_dog`, so the
assignment is correct.

Your declaration `struct dog **ptr` creates an object `ptr` whose type is
"pointer to a pointer to a `struct dog`.  If you take the address of
`ptr_to_dog`, you get an expression whose type is "pointer to a pointer to
`struct dog`.  This is the same type as the `ptr` you declared, so if you were
to make the assignment `ptr = &ptr_to_dog`, that is valid.

Now let's look at the right side of the assignment, `&frodo.name`.  Note that
`.` is said to "bind tighter" than the `&`, so this is the same as
`&(frodo.name)`.  The expression `frodo.name` gets the value of the field `name`
in the `foo` object, which is of type `struct dog`.  So the expression
`&frodo.name` gives a pointer to that field, so its type is "pointer to the
field `name` in the `frodo` object. The type of `name` is "array of 10 `int`s",
so `&frodo.name` is "pointer to an array of 10 `int`s".  So the declaration you
gave could be described as "get the pointer to the array of 10 `int`s `name` and
assign it to the "pointer to the pointer to the `struct dog` `foo`" `ptr`.  The
types are not compatible. However, all pointers can be reduced to a kind of
unnamed type "pointer to memory", so the compiler can convert the "pointer to 10
`int`s" `&frodo.name` to the "pointer to the pointer to `frodo`" `ptr`.  This is
almost never usefull, so most compiler will emit a warning about this.

Now you could do this `struct dog * ptr_to_dog = &frodo`, which assigns the address of
`frodo` to the "pointer to a `struct dog`" `ptr_to_dog`, so here the types match and
the assignment is proper.  Note that a "pointer to `struct dog`" does not mean
"pointer to a single `struct dog`"; so pointer could point to memory that hold
an indefinite series of `struct dog`s in succession, ie an array.  So you can do
`ptr_to_dog[3]`, which means "get the fourth `struct dog` from the series of
`struct dog`s beginning at the address `ptr_to_dog`.  If `ptr_to_dog` contains
only one `struct dog`, what you get from that will be meaningless, but it is a
valid expression.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
frodo.name[i]=i;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
printf(" frodo.name[%d]%d\n",i,frodo.name[i]);

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
printf(" ptr =%d\n",ptr[i]);
}
```

Remember that the type of `ptr` is "pointer to a pointer to a `struct dog`, but
given your assignment, `ptr` does not point to a pointer to a `struct dog`; it
points to an "array of 10 `int`s" in the field `name` of the `struct dog`
object `frodo`.  So the value of `ptr` here is meaningless; its value is some
section of the memory of the `name` array interpreted as a "pointer to a pointer
to `struct dog`".  From this I take it that you wanted `ptr` to point to the
"array of 10 `int`s" called `name` in the `struct dog` object `frodo`.  To get
this, the declaration should have been

```
int * ptr = frodo.name;
```

Remember that an array type (`name`) can be assigned to a pointer to its inner
type (`int`), in which the array expression (`frodo.name`) will "decay" into
that type of pointer.  This this says "get the array of 10 `int`s `name` inside
the `struct dog` `frodo`, decay it to a pointer to the beginning of the series
of `int`s in `name` and assign that pointer to the pointer to `int`s called
`ptr`".  A proper assignment.

Note that @tstanisl's answer is wrong in one place; it declares `ptr` to be a
"pointer to `char`".  But `frodo.name` consists of `int`s not `char`s, so his
assignment is invalid.  The expression `&frodo.name[0]` says "get the first
`int` in the array of 10 `int`s `frodo.name` and take its address, yielding a
"pointer to the first `int` in `frodo.name`".  But the address of the first
`int` here is also the address of the series of `int`s in `frodo.name`.  So
the address `&frodo.name` and `frodo.name` when it is "decayed" to a
pointer-to-`int` have the same value and type.

Here is your code, fixed with the above in mind:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct dog
{
    int name[10];
    char breed[10];
    int age;
    char color[10];
};

int main()
{
struct dog frodo;
int *ptr= frodo.name;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
frodo.name[i]=i;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
printf(" frodo.name[%d]%d\n",i,frodo.name[i]);

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
printf(" ptr =%d\n",ptr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer. Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I expect that `ptr` should be a pointer to the first element of `frodo.name` which is array of 10 `int`s. Therefore the type of `ptr` should be `int*`. Use:

```
int *ptr=&frodo.name[0];
```

Comment: name is an array of ints.

Comment: @stark, fixed, thanx, very confusing to use `int` for a member called `name`

Comment: Alternately, just `int *ptr = frodo.name;` since array expressions "decay" to pointers to their first element.